# Authenticating Heroku gem from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I am trying to get my automatic backup script to work. I am using the heroku gem. The script is being run from Heroku's Scheduler addon.

```
require "heroku/command/pg"
require "heroku/command/pg_backups"

....
def initialize
  @client     = Heroku::Command::Pg.new([], app: ENV['APP_NAME'])
end

...
attachment = @client.send(:generate_resolver)
...
```

As soon as I call `attachment = @client.send(:generate_resolver)`, the scripts stops execution and ask for

```
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email:
```

Is there a way to avoid this, given that the task is being initiated from within heroku anyway and therefore should already be authenticated.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-interactive login, you need to use an API key, which Heroku [will read](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/36b48d18c34323f4d5f900130298d8a0ff2b684a/lib/heroku/auth.rb#L155-L157) from the `HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable. You can [fetch the key](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication) for your account from a logged-in CLI using `heroku auth:token`.

There's no way to avoid authentication just because you're running inside Heroku already. That would have significant inter-app security implications.

Also check out [pgbackups-archive](https://github.com/kjohnston/pgbackups-archive). Looks like it does what you're after, or at least might have some useful techniques for you.

Comment: I see, do you know if the token changes over time?

Comment: The token doesn't change on its own, but I believe it'll change if you change your password. You can also regenerate the it at any time from your [account page](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account).